# Create a subscription from a previous transaction

Tags: php, api, subscription, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

This is an Authorize.net question...I am looking for a way to create a subscription from a previous payment a customer has made through an API call or another way instead of having to login to the Merchant Interface. I have done some research but currently have not found a way to do this. Is this possible?

Also, in the Merchant Interface, there is a "View Rebillable Transactions" button that allows you to submit a charge to a card the customer has used in the past. Is it possible to have this same functionality using an API?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet. It's something they are considering but as of right now you can only do it either using the ARB API by making it immediately or doing it through the merchant interface.

Comment: it would be really nice if they added this feature. This would save sooo much time. Do you know of a timeline? Thanks

Comment: Last time I spoke them was about a year ago and they didn't have a timeline for this. They didn't actually commit to it either but based on community feedback I'd be stunned if they didn't ultimately introduce this feature.

Comment: That sounds promising. I really, really cannot wait until they add this. I will be one happy person when they do! Thanks for your info